# MariaDB not solution

Tags: mariadb

Hello stackoverflow community, how are you all?
I have the problem in my database I need to dump my database but my mariadb does not want to start.
Below I put the status presented.

```
root@localhost:~# service mysql status
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.1.45 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─limits.conf, migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-11-20 22:42:44 UTC; 7s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 5588 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 5578 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0
  Process: 5573 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5571 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5588 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Nov 20 22:42:41 localhost mysqld[5588]: 2022-11-20 22:42:41 139745456523520 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.47-87.0 started; log sequence number 616854704160
Nov 20 22:42:41 localhost mysqld[5588]: 2022-11-20 22:42:41 139744889497344 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
Nov 20 22:42:41 localhost mysqld[5588]: 2022-11-20 22:42:41 139745456523520 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Nov 20 22:42:41 localhost mysqld[5588]: 2022-11-20 22:42:41 139745456523520 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
Nov 20 22:42:41 localhost mysqld[5588]: 2022-11-20 22:42:41 139745456523520 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
Nov 20 22:42:41 localhost mysqld[5588]: 2022-11-20 22:42:41 139745456523520 [ERROR] Aborting
Nov 20 22:42:44 localhost systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 20 22:42:44 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.45 database server.
Nov 20 22:42:44 localhost systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 20 22:42:44 localhost systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I couldn't move forward because I don't have enough knowledge, can someone help me.

Comment: It does seem to be something to do with mmap support. How host environment are you running. Its required with two transactional engines. If you have tokudb enabled and you aren't using you might avoid this by disabling tokudb. `--skip-tokudb` (guess).

Comment: Check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/985485/mariadb-docker-cant-init-tc-log-when-using-mounted-storage). What is your filesystem and host environment?

Comment: [Activate binary log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/activating-the-binary-log/) seems to be the common workaround.